# Read text file in scala command Line

Tags: scala, user-defined-functions, scala-collections

I am trying to read a text file via scala command line.
The code compiles correctly, but it fails on execution due to file not found error.

```
import scala.io.Source

object Mainclass extends App {
    val filename = "filo.txt"
    for(line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines) {
      println(line)
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
scala Main.scala:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: filo.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Comment: Your code runs without error for me (after I created the `filo.txt` file).

Answer (score 2):

Since filo.txt is a relative file path you need to make sure that the running program uses the location of  filo.txt as the working directory.

Example:

```
echo 'my test data' > ~/mydir/filo.txt
cd ~/mydir
scala Main.scala
```

So when you run this program it needs to be started in mydir.  You could avoid this by using a fully qualified path.

Comment: I tried both replacing the relative path with Absolute Path and placing the file in same directory of Main.scala.Though it did not helped.

Comment: Please attach the directory listing of where you are running the program.

Comment: This the directory:D:\Spark\cmdscala\helloworld\src\main\scala       
 below is the code                                                                              import scala.util
import scala.io.Source

object Mainclass  extends App
{
val filename = 'filo.txt'
for(line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines) {
    println(line)
}
}  i am running in windows cmd

Comment: Can you do a `dir` listing for the  scala directory?

Comment: it worked..i did not realized the filo.txt is actually filo.txt.txt